# AfterLogic Webmail Lite Web Server Setup

Tags: email, mail-server, webmail

I'm working on setting up AfterLogic Webmail Lite for my web server.  I have a VPS through http://dreamhost.com, and I host multiple different domains on this box.

I'm looking into setting up a Webmail interface that I can theme to match my site design that can be used by all my clients.  I want my clients to be able to go to www.thoughtspacedesigns.com/mail, and log into their account (even if their account is something like admin@ultimate-vending.com).

So far, I've been successful in setting up webmail per domain.  I was able to download and install AfterLogic on http://www.thoughtspacedesigns.com/webmail, however I can only seem to set up thoughtspacedesigns.com accounts to work through this interface.  It seems that any accounts hosted under a different domain name can't be added as users to this install.

Basically, I'm looking to have a single, free, themed portal that my clients can use to check their webmail.  I don't wan to install different instances of this portal per domain.  If anybody knows how to configure AfterLogic Webmail Lite to work on multiple domains, or another free solution that would handle this request, help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Even if nobody is familiar with AfterLogic, any recommendations for free or open source mail server software would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I represent AfterLogic support team.

Main question here is: are all those domains hosted by the same mail server? Current edition of WebMail Lite is designed to work with a single IMAP/SMTP mail host, so if you'd like to access multiple email hosts, I'm afraid it's not going to work with WebMail Lite - at least, not without deep tweaking. You might consider using the Pro version instead.

But if this is actually the case of all the domains hosted by the same mail server, you simply need to supply its host details in default domain settings, and any user on that mail server should be able to log in, regardless of the domain.

While there's no guaranteed free support for Lite version, you're welcome to post your questions at community forum: http://www.afterlogic.com/forum/forum_topics.asp?FID=21

Comment: All of these domains are indeed on the same mail server.  I put the webmail portal on thoughtspacedesigns.com/webmail, but if I go there and try to log in with a abileneloving.com account (another domain on the same web server), It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: To find out what might be causing this, you need to enable debug logging in AdminPanel, replicate the problem and see what's in the log file. Most likely, logs will contain either response from mail server or internal error message of WebMail. Consider posting relevant bit of the logs at community forum.

Answer (score 1):

I have a DreamHost standard account rather than VPS, so this may be different for you. I installed AfterLogic Webmail Lite, created SQL tables, etc, pointed it to the main domain for mail servers (mail.mydomain.com), enabled SSL, and left the advanced settings as default.

Users go to https://www.mydomain.com/webmail (since I have secure hosting and a p, and they can login to any of my DreamHost-hosted email accounts.

Since the default has users use their full email address as the username, and since any hosted `mail.\*.\*` actually goes to `(YourAssignedMailserver).mail.dreamhost.com` anyway (in my case `mx1.sub4.homie.mail.dreamhost.com`), users can log in using their full email address, and it doesn't matter what domain their address is actually on.

Webmail hides the certificate errors that users could see (since the presented hostname doesn't match the certificate name) if they use their own client. Users under other hosting accounts may not work, since they may be assigned a different mailserver, but I expect any user on the same server will.

With VPS, I expect you can host your own email server, which has the potential of resolving certificate issues, but it may cause other complications.